# Native C++ extension for electron.atom.io

Tags: c++, node.js, electron

I would like to build a C++ native extension for electron.
I started with the [hello](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) sample: I built the node libraries, the sample and tested successfully with node (v4.5.0).
To use with electron I have to build against the electron V8 version. I followed this [guide](http://electron.atom.io/docs/development/build-instructions-windows/) to build the node library: I generated the msvc VS2015 projects, but when I build I get this error:

```
\cares.vcxproj(360,5): error MSB3073: The command "call ninja.exe -C ..\..\..\..\out\Debug_x64\ cares" exited with code 1.
```

And this happens for all projects. How can I solve it?

Comment: Out of interest can you call ninja by itself (and maybe get better error info from it)?

Comment: Ops, I didn't have the ninja in the path... I was able to build node.lib (x64) with vcbuild.bat. I included the node headers and lib in the electron path, but when I run I get  "Error: Module did not self-register". I used a prebuilt x64 Electron 6.3.0, the same version as the one I used to build my module...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build Electron from source to build a native Node module, you should follow the same advice I gave [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39250106/1259938).

Comment: Ok I followed the hints. I was able to build node.lib (x64) with vcbuild.bat in the electron vendor folder. I was able to use node-gyp to make the vcxproj form my project, bui the build failed (could not find the  node.lib). I opened the vcxproj, added the lib path and built with success. And now I can use my native C++ extension in the electron render process!