# Building Electron Native Extensions using Visual Basic 2015

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, electron

### Where I am currently:

I have began working on a NodeJS native extension I intend to work with Electron, but from previous works I have noted that the build steps for building for just NodeJS are as expected, include the libraries as per instruction and change to output a .dll file with a .node extension.

### The problem I am facing:

When compiling my extension, which tried and tested within NodeJS, does not work within an Electron contained instance of NodeJS - from searching around I understand this to be a problem with the header files which I am compiling against etc. The documentation for building with visual studio (**not Visual Studio Code**) is very sparse and everywhere generally points to using node-gyp - which is something I'm attempting to avoid and build using purely Visual Studio 2015.

For reference, when running the working (in NodeJS) NativeExtension I get the following error (which googling brought me to the conclusion I am compiling against the wrong thing):

```
ELECTRON_ASAR.js:167 Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register.
```

Could someone please shed some light on where I may be going wrong? I am a novice when it comes to C++ program structure and compiling methodologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The documentation for building with visual studio (not Visual Studio Code) is very sparse and everywhere generally points to using node-gyp - which is something I'm attempting to avoid and build using purely Visual Studio 2015.

There is a standard way of compiling native Node modules, and as a self admitted novice it would be unwise to deviate from it. I suggest you read through the [Microsoft NodeJS guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#configuring-your-windows-development-environment) and get your development environment properly configured to build via `node-gyp`, once that's working you can start figuring out [how to rebuild native Node modules for Electron](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have before used node-gyp to build my native extension for Electron (with success!), but due to my environment (I'm currently employed as a junior Javascript developer, but have been assigned to testing the NodeJS/Electron/NativeExtension stack with our product) and the build steps related to our other product[s] I am looking to abstract the compile steps so the native extension can be compiled along side the rest the product line. I have everything set up correctly in terms of standardised build but ultimately am looking for guidance on files to include, libs etc.

Comment: `node-gyp configure` should generate a `.vcxproj` file, so perhaps you can integrate that into your build.

Comment: I'm going ahead and marking this as correct considering I've not found another solution to my problem, and from watching Paul Betts' 'Electron Native Extensions' talk, it seems this is the legitimate method of compiling with Electrons headers. My original concern was based on the lifespan of the node-gyp project, but from further research I believe that node-gyp is probably not going away anytime soon. Thanks for your input, appreciate you taking the time to reply to me.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson `node-gyp` is the official way to build NodeJS addons, as long as NodeJS exists it's not going anywhere (and even if it does, something similar will replace it).